# For loop for files in multiple folders - bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, loops, for-loop

I need to have files from many directories in a for loop.
As for now, I have the following code:

```
for f in ./test1/*;
...
for f in ./test2/*;
...
for f in ./test3/*;
...
```

In each loop I'm doing the same thing. Is there a way to get files from multiple folders?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try `for f in ./{test1,test2,test3}/*` or `for f in ./*/*` depending on what you want.

Answer (score 20):

You can give multiple "words" to `for`, so the simplest answer is:

```
for f in ./test1 ./test2 ./test3; do
  ...
done
```

There are then various tricks to reduce the amount of typing; namely globbing and brace expansion.

```
# the shell searchs for matching filenames 
for f in ./test?; do 
...
# the brace syntax expands with each given string
for f in ./test{1,2,3}; do
...
# same thing but using integer sequences
for f in ./test{1..3}
```