# How to pass variable (list of folders) to for-loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm new-ish to Linux, and a beginner to programming, but have been able to patch together a few lines of code [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/)  for passing a list of files to a for-loop, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122341/for-loop-for-files-in-multiple-folders-bash-shell) for doing the same with folders.

```
# Run search.sh from base folder; 
# Only interested in folders under base folder (e.g., baseFolder/FolderA)
# list all folders in base directory that match search parameters;
# cut out just the folder name; feed to variable DIR

 DIR=$(find . -name *MTL.txt | cut -d '/' -f2)

# echo $DIR = "FolderA FolderB FolderC"
# place that information in a for-loop

    for i in $DIR; do

      cd $DIR # step into folder

      # find specific file in folder for processing
      FILE=$(find -name *MTL | cut -d '/' -f2)

      # copy in a static file from another folder;
      # rename file based on file name found in previous step
      cp /baseFolder/staticfile.txt $FILE.new
      do more stuff

      cd .. # step out of directory

     done
```

The code completes fine for the first directory, but fails to move into subsequent directories. I'm guessing that one of my (many) problems is that I just can't pass a list of folder names to $DIR like I am. This should be pretty simple, but my foo is weak.

Please sensei, show me the way.

EDIT:

Changing "cd $DIR" to "cd $i" had the desired effect. Code now loops through all directories and performs operations correctly within each.
-Thx to core1024 for flagging the above.

Comment: By the way... Don't you miss a dot '.' in 'FILE=$(find -name *MTL | cut -d '/' -f2)
' after 'find'?

Comment: I am not expert, but I think that `cd $DIR # step into folder` should be `cd $i # step into folder`

Comment: @core1024: just faced palmed myself. Changing that one small thing in my code made everything work! Can you please post as an answer? Thx.

Comment: @SkippyFastol: I removed the "." in the find command and it didn't make a difference either way. My understanding is that it is meant to keep the find command situated within the current directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not expert, but I think that `cd $DIR # step into folder` should be `cd $i # step into folder`

Answer (score 4):

> cd .. # step out of directory

just steps up ONE LEVEL.

You need, before the loop, to store your "base directory" in a variable :

```
BASEDIR=`pwd`
```

Then, you'll perform

```
cd $BASEDIR # step out of directory
```

instead of your current

> cd ..

Comment: Based on how he generates `DIR`, he's never going more than one level deep with `cd`.

Comment: @chepner: now that you mention it ... But that doesn't make my suggestion less legit :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a "For loop" though. The find command will already loop through all the items it finds.

there is a -exec option on the find command that passes every item "found" to a specific command.

e.g.

```
find . -name *MTL.txt -exec cp {} /basefolder \;
```

this will copy all files found to /basefolder

if you feel strongly about using a for loop you can also use output from a command as list to the loop.

e.g.

```
for MYVAR in `ls *.txt* `
do
    echo $MYVAR
done
```

Using cut is generally not a good idea unless you are formatting output or have a command that does not send its output to stdout.

Comment: Never, *ever* do `for var in \`ls\``. [Seriously](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). `for MYVAR in *.txt*`

Answer (score 0):

The following is a little simpler, since it doesn't need to parse `find` output:

```
for subdir in *; do
  if [[ ! -d $subdir ]]; then
    continue
  fi

  cd $subdir
  for f in *MTL.txt; do
    cp /baseFolder/staticFile.txt $f.new
    # And whatever else
  done

  cd ..
done
```

Note that I only descend into each subdirectory once, where your original code would do it multiple times. I point this out in case that was your intention. Also, since your `cut` command prevented you from going more than one directory deep, I assumed that was your intention.

Depending on the other stuff you do, you may be able to avoid changing directories altogether. For example:

```
for f in $subdir/*MTL.txt; do
  cp /baseFolder/staticFile.txt $f.new
  # More stuff
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code will break if directory name has embedded spaces. And if you have multiple files satisfying the find condition in a directory, you will also repeat the action.
Alternative:

```
IFS='
'
declare -a DIR
declare -a FILE
DIR=($(find . -name '*MTL.txt' | cut -f2 -d '/' | uniq))
for x in "${DIR[@]}"
 do
   if [ -d "$x" ];  then
     pushd "$x"
        FILE=($(ls *MTL))
        for y in "${FILE[@]}"
          do
            cp /baseFolder/staticfile.txt  "$y"
            echo do more stuff
          done
     popd
   fi
 done
```

Comment: `ls` isn't necessary. `FILE=(*)`