# How to loop through the sorted list of file names in two directories

Tags: bash, for-loop, whitespace

Please note, i have read entries like [For loop for files in multiple folders - bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122341/for-loop-for-files-in-multiple-folders-bash-shell) and they ask for a significantly different thing.

I want to loop through the file names in a sorted order that exist in either of two directories. Files can potentially have spaces in them.

Let's say i have:

```
1/
  a
  a c b
  b
  c
2/
  a
  d
```

I would want to loop through: 'a', 'a c b', 'b', 'c', 'd'.

I have tried to do the following:

```
for fname in $((ls -1 -f -A "${dir1}"; ls -1 -f -A "${dir2}")|sort --unique); do
  echo "testing ${fname}"
done
```

the result then is

```
testing .
testing ..
testing a
testing a
testing c
testing b
testing b
testing c
testing d
```

For whatever reason i am getting '.' and '..' entries, that i was trying to exclude with `-A`, and also the file 'a c b' gets broken down into three strings.

I have tried to resolve it by adding `--zero` to the `sort` command, that changed nothing; by quoting the whole `$(ls...|sort)` part, and has resulted into a single entry into the for loop that has received the entire string with multiple lines each of which contained filename.

Comment: `for fname in 1/* 2/*; do ...; done`?

Comment: Please add your desired output to your question.

Comment: Hi, actually the desired output is already there: "I would want to loop through: 'a', 'a c b', 'b', 'c', 'd'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**

1. Change the for delimiter from whitespace to `\n` using the following command:

   ```
   IFS=$'\n'
   ```
2. You used `-l` for ls which implies `-a` (and overrides `-A`); Use `--color=never` instead.

**To summarize:**

```
IFS=$'\n'
for fname in $((ls -1 --color=never -A "${dir1}"; ls -1 --color=never -A "${dir2}")|sort --unique); do
  echo "testing ${fname}"
done
```

Comment: In bash, you need to use `IFS=$'\n'` and not `IFS=\n`, I fixed it

Answer (score 4):

Do not consciously ever parse output of `ls` command(See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) ), it has lots of potential pitfalls. Use the `find` command with its `-print0` option to null delimit the files so that file name with spaces/newline or any meta-charactetrs are handled and subsequently use GNU `sort` with the same null delimit character, to sort them alphabetically & remove duplicate files. If `dir1` and `dir2` are shell variables containing the names of the folders to look up, you can do

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
done< <(find "${dir1}" "${dir2}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\0" | sort -t / -u -z)
```

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler approach might be to loop over everything and exclude duplicates by other means.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Keep an associative array of which names you have already processed
# Requires Bash 4
declare -A done
for file in 1/* 2/*; do
    base=${file#*/}  # trim directory prefix from value
    test "${done[$base]}" && continue
    : do things ...
    done["$base"]="$file"
done
```

Comment: I think that this would make it very difficult to sort the filenames.

Comment: Au contraire, `done | sort` at the end, provided you `echo "$base"` or something like that in the `: do things ...` section.

Comment: and then i would have to capture this output and put it into yet another loop to actually process them?

Comment: Hm, yeah, if your requirement is to process the files in strictly alphabetical order then this is probably not the answer you want, or at least not the most elegant solution.